# .NET Core : Areas attribute route value not passed correctly

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

Area route link with parameter returns

```
`/admin/home/edituser/b36c7c26`
```

instead of

```
`/admin/home/edituser?id=b36c7c26`
```

This in turns scatters my interface, meanwhile am using the standard ASP.NET tag helper link generator

`asp-action="edituser" asp-controller="home" asp-area="admin" asp-route-id="@user.Id"`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The asp-route-{value} attribute enables a wildcard route prefix. Any value occupying the {value} placeholder is interpreted as a potential route parameter. If a default route isn't found, this route prefix is appended to the generated href attribute as a request parameter and value. Otherwise, it's substituted in the route template.

`id` is found in your route template so it is not appended as a request parameter and value.  Your template is probably the typical default:

```
"{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0